Is davening with one's hands clasped behind the back something that is frowned up in Judaism?
Does davening with your hands behind your back present too relaxed of an attitude for proper prayer?  I vaguely remember hearing or seeing this somewhere but cannot seem to remember where.  Or maybe I am not recalling it accurately at all!

Pretty sure I've seen something from the Arizal against it. See also: https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/hand-positions-according-to-halacha-and-kaballa/

"frowned upon in Judaism" and no halacha tag makes me confident to bring my anecdotal experience that I've seen several chashuva people daven like this in my time

The article cited in a comment above from @shmosel https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/hand-positions-according-to-halacha-and-kaballa/ shows two diametrically opposed views. So the answer is either yes or no.
In the body of the article it states: “Based on Kabala, one is not to place his hands behind his back.” Footnote 18 includes the following: Other opinions: “Some Poskim rule it is permitted to hold the hands behind one’s back and it is even exemplary to do so during prayer.”

IIRC, the Mishnah Berurah rules against holding one's hands behind one's back
